# inherit value from another class in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to keep the value which is entered in the Edit text by the users.
then I want to use that entered value in a different class.basically i want the user to enter their username in this class

```
public class Loginpage extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    EditText usern,passw,dis;
    Button ulogin;
    String k;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.loginpage);
        usern=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.usern);
        passw=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.passw);
        dis=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.dis);
        ulogin=(Button) findViewById(R.id.ulogin);
        ulogin.setOnClickListener(this);
        k=usern.getText().toString();
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View p) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(p.getId()){
        case R.id.ulogin:
            k=usern.getText().toString();
            String passwd=passw.getText().toString();
            Process cat = new Process(this);
            cat.open();
            String returnpass = cat.getpass(k);
            cat.close();
            if(passwd.equals(returnpass))
            {
                Intent i=new Intent("com.example.billpay.USEROPTION");
                startActivity(i);
                Dialog r=new Dialog(this);
                r.setTitle("Login Successfull");
                TextView wg= new TextView(this);
                wg.setText("Success");
                r.setContentView(wg);
                r.show();

            }
            else
            {
                Dialog r=new Dialog(this);
                r.setTitle("Wrong Username or Password");
                TextView po= new TextView(this);
                po.setText("Failure");
                r.setContentView(po);
                r.show();
            }


        }

    }


}
```

then i want to use their value which they have entered in the edit text in another class which is this.I want to display their username in this page.

```
 public class Userprofile extends Loginpage {


    TextView pra;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.userprofile);
        pra=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.pra);
        EditText p=usern;
        String op=p.getText().toString();
        pra.setText(k);

    }

}
```

but i am not being able to display their value

Comment: Inheritance is not needed here, what you want is just pass a value.... http://stackoverflow.com/q/2091465/2001247

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first class:

```
Context c=getApplicationContext();
String username;
```

Once you have your String with your username:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(c, YourSecondClass.class);
intent.putExtra("username", username);
startActivity(intent);
```

In your second class:

```
String username;
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle=getIntent.getExtras();
username=bundle.getString("username");
```

EDIT:

In case the second class is not called directly from the frist, you should use SharedPreferences:

First, create a folder called "shared_prefs" in the root of your project. Inside that folder, create a xml file, with the name you want. Inside that xml:

```
<map>
<string name="mail">user@mail.com</string>
<tring name="other">othervariable</tring>
</map>
```

In code, to reach that variable, you do this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView mail;
Context c;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    c=getApplicationContext();

    //Putting values in preferences.xml
    SharedPreferences prefs =
             getSharedPreferences("preferences",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();     
    editor.putString("mail", "correo@mail.com");
    editor.commit();

            //Getting things from preferences.xml
    String correo=prefs.getString("mail", null);
    mail=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mail);
    mail.setText(correo);

}



}
```

Comment: what is Yoursecondclass.class

Comment: I thought you called the second class, where you need the username, directly from frist class. In that case, Bundle is simpler. In your case, you need to put a variable reachable to every class of your app, you must use SharedPreferences. Ill edit the answer with a simple how-to.

Comment: what code i should write in my first class from where i need to store my username and what code should i write where i need to retrieve that stored username

Comment: I think you shold start by reading something if you need to ask that... You want to store a value in preferences.xml, so if you have a String named "username", should be editor.putString("thenameofthetaginthexmlfile", username);

Answer (score 0):

simply use -[Shared Preference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

to store value and retrive value in other class

Comment: can you tell me how to use shared preferences

Answer (score 0):

Please use -Shared Preference:

here an easy example how to do it:

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

Comment: i am not able to understand how to use shared preferences